# Records Display Only On First Page

Tags: php, pagination

The page loads properly with the results in a table (variables/values passed on correctly from the initial page); with correct number of records as per set 'limit'; the pagination correctly divides the records into pages.

Two things that I need help with in the code:

1) The pagination is supposed to display 'Previous 1 2 3 ... 6 7 8 Next'; but instead displays 'Previous 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 Next'. The code seems fine to me - tried looking up various posts online but not found anything to resolve this.

2) After the page loads the results, I click on the next page and it goes to the next page but no records are displayed (blank table; but all other static items are displayed). I checked and the 'page' variable is passed on to the next page. It does not bring up any errors either.

I have limited knowledge of PHP, have read couple of posts but not been able to resolve.

Below is the code - if anyone can assist I would greatly appreciate it.
Filename: display.php
The variables are passed on from previous file: index.php

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">

<!-- INCLUDE THE CSS STYLESHEET FILE -->
<link href="Stylesheet/vehicles_stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="Stylesheet/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<?php 
    include("header.php"); 
?>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
====some javascript code here ===
</script>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#DADADA" onLoad="MM_preloadImages('images/ContactSellerOVR.gif','images/SearchAgainOVR.jpg')">

<?php 

//Get Values from previous page
@$VehName = $_POST['VehName'];
@$VehModel = $_POST['VehModel'];
if ($VehModel=='')
{
$VehModel="%";
}
@$YearFrom = $_POST['YearFrom'];
if ($YearFrom=='')
{
$YearFrom=1960;
}
@$YearTo = $_POST['YearTo'];
if ($YearTo=='')
{
$YearTo=date('Y');
}
@$Price = $_POST['Price'];
if ($Price=='')
{
$Price="%";
}
@$Location = $_POST['Location'];
if ($Location=='')
{
$Location="%";
}

switch ($Price)
{
case "A":
    $PriceSearch = "' AND VehPrice BETWEEN 0 AND 500000 ";
    break;
case "B":
    $PriceSearch = "' AND VehPrice BETWEEN 500000 AND 1000000 ";
    break;
case "C":
    $PriceSearch = "' AND VehPrice BETWEEN 1000000 AND 2000000 ";
    break;
case "D":
    $PriceSearch = "' AND VehPrice BETWEEN 2000000 AND 3000000 ";
    break;
case "E":
    $PriceSearch = "' AND VehPrice BETWEEN 3000000 AND 5000000 ";
    break;
case "F":
    $PriceSearch = "' AND VehPrice BETWEEN 5000001 AND 99000000 ";
    break;
default:
    $PriceSearch = "' AND VehPrice BETWEEN 0 AND 99000000 ";
}
?>

<table width="1000" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" align="center" border="0" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<tr>
    <td align="center">
        <a href="index.php" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Search Again','','images/SearchAgainOVR.jpg',1)"><img src="images/SearchAgain.jpg" name="Search Again" width="160" height="40" border="0" align="middle"></a> 
    </td>
</tr>
</table>

<?php
include('Connections/VehicleConn.php');
$tbl_name="vehicledetails";     // table name
$adjacents = 4;              // How many adjacent pages should be shown on each side

//     Get total number of rows in data table 
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM vehicledetails WHERE VehName LIKE '" . $VehName . 
                "' AND VehModel LIKE '" . $VehModel . "' 
                AND VehYear BETWEEN '" . $YearFrom . "' AND '" . $YearTo . 
                $PriceSearch . " ORDER BY VehDateadded DESC" ;              

$total_pages = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
$total_pages = $total_pages['num'];

/* Setup vars for query. */
$targetpage = "display.php";    //the name of this file
$limit = 3;             // how many items to show per page

$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 0;
if($page)
    $start = ($page - 1) * $limit;      //first item to display on this page
else
    $start = 0;             //if no page var is given, set start to 0   

// Get data
$sql = "SELECT * FROM vehicledetails WHERE VehName LIKE '" . $VehName . 
                "' AND VehModel LIKE '" . $VehModel . "' 
                AND VehYear BETWEEN '" . $YearFrom . "' AND '" . $YearTo . 
                $PriceSearch . " ORDER BY VehDateadded DESC LIMIT " . $start . ", " . $limit ;
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());


// Setup page vars for display
if ($page == 0) $page = 1;  //if no page var is given, default to 1
$prev = $page - 1;  //previous page is page - 1
$next = $page + 1;  //next page is page + 1
$lastpage = ceil($total_pages/$limit);  //lastpage is = total pages / items per page, rounded up.
$lpm1 = $lastpage - 1;          //last page minus 1

/* 
Apply rules and draw the pagination object 
Save the code to a variable in case required to draw it more than once.
*/
$pagination = "";
if($lastpage > 1)
{   
    $pagination .= "<div class=\"pagination\">";
//previous button
if ($page > 1) 
    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$prev\">Previous</a>";
else
    $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">Previous</span>";           
//pages 
if ($lastpage < 7 + ($adjacents * 2))   //not enough pages to bother breaking it up
    {   
    for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
        {
        if ($counter == $page)
            $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
        else
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";         
        }
    }
elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($adjacents * 2))    //enough pages to hide some
    {
    //close to beginning; only hide later pages
    if($page < 1 + ($adjacents * 2))        
        {
        for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++)
            {
            if ($counter == $page)
            $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
            else
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";     
            }
        $pagination.= "...";
        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";
        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>";       
        }       
                    //in middle; hide some front and some back
    elseif($lastpage - ($adjacents * 2) > $page && $page > ($adjacents * 2))
        {
        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=1\">1</a>";
        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=2\">2</a>";
        $pagination.= "...";
        for ($counter = $page - $adjacents; $counter <= $page + $adjacents; $counter++)
        {
            if ($counter == $page)
                $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
            else
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";     
        }
        $pagination.= "...";
        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";
        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>";       
    }
    //close to end; only hide early pages
    else
    {
        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=1\">1</a>";
        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=2\">2</a>";
        $pagination.= "...";
        for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
            {
            if ($counter == $page)
            $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
        else
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";     
            }
    }
    }
    //next button
    if ($page < $counter - 1) 
        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$next\">Next</a>";
    else
    $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">Next</span>";
$pagination.= "</div>\n";       
}
?>

<table width="1000" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" align="center" border="1" bordercolor="#F7F7F7" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<?php
// While loop to display records
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
?>  
    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" width="320"> 
        <blockquote>
    <h1><?php echo $row['VehName']; ?>&nbsp;<?php echo $row['VehModel']; ?>&nbsp;(<?php echo $row['VehYear']; ?>)</h1>
    <NormalText><br>
        <?php echo $row['VehMileage']; ?>kms&nbsp;-&nbsp;<?php echo $row['VehTransmission']; ?>&nbsp;-&nbsp;<?php echo $row['VehEngine']; ?>cc 
        <br>
        <?php echo $row['VehCategory']; ?>&nbsp;-&nbsp;<?php echo $row['VehColour']; ?>&nbsp;-&nbsp;<?php echo $row['VehFuel']; ?> 
        <br>
        Vehicle Location: <?php echo $row['VehLocation']; ?>
        <br>
        <strong>Price: KShs. <?php echo $row['VehPrice']; ?> </strong><br>
        <br>
    </NormalText>
        <form name="displaycontact" action="contactseller.php" target="_blank" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="<?php echo $row['VehID']; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="NAME" value="<?php echo $row['VehName']; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="MODEL" value="<?php echo $row['VehModel']; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="YEAR" value="<?php echo $row['VehYear']; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="MILEAGE" value="<?php echo $row['VehMileage']; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="TRANSMISSION" value="<?php echo $row['VehTransmission']; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="ENGINE" value="<?php echo $row['VehEngine']; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="CATEGORY" value="<?php echo $row['VehCategory']; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="COLOUR" value="<?php echo $row['VehColour']; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="FUEL" value="<?php echo $row['VehFuel']; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="LOCATION" value="<?php echo $row['VehLocation']; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="PRICE" value="<?php echo $row['VehPrice']; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="CONTACTNAME" value="<?php echo $row['VehContactname']; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="CONTACTEMAIL" value="<?php echo $row['VehContactemail']; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="CONTACTTEL" value="<?php echo $row['VehContacttel']; ?>">
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Contact Seller"> </form>
    </blockquote>
    </td>
        <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" width="680" align="center"> 
    <a href="images/<?php echo $row['VehImage1']; ?>" rel="lightbox" title=""><img src="images/<?php echo $row['VehImage1']; ?>" align="middle" border="0" width="100" height="100"></a><a href="images/<?php echo $row['VehImage2']; ?>" rel="lightbox" title=""><img src="images/<?php echo $row['VehImage2']; ?>" align="middle" border="0" width="100" height="100"></a><a href="images/<?php echo $row['VehImage3']; ?>" rel="lightbox" title=""><img src="images/<?php echo $row['VehImage3']; ?>" align="middle" border="0" width="100" height="100"></a><a href="images/<?php echo $row['VehImage4']; ?>" rel="lightbox" title=""><img src="images/<?php echo $row['VehImage4']; ?>" align="middle" border="0" width="100" height="100"></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php
}
?>

</table>
<table width="1000" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<tr align="center">
    <td align="center">
    <?php
    echo $pagination
    ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<?php
include("footer.php"); 
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code given here is quite long. Hint: try and concentrate on the central issue. And then another "off-topic" hint that comes to my mind: When you want to set default values for form variables I found the following method helpful: first set the variables to their default values and then `extract` the `$_REQUEST` or `$_POST` array, like `$VehName='noname';$VehModel=$Price=$Location='%';$YearFrom=1960;$YearTo=date('Y');
extract($_POST);`.

Comment: Thanks, very useful suggestion - will apply to my code

Answer (score 0):

Fallowing code worked for me

```
include('connect-db.php');

                        // number of results to show per page
                                        $per_page = 150;

                                        // figure out the total pages in the database
                                        if ($result = $mysqli->query(""SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM vehicledetails WHERE VehName LIKE '" . $VehName . 
                "' AND VehModel LIKE '" . $VehModel . "' 
                AND VehYear BETWEEN '" . $YearFrom . "' AND '" . $YearTo . 
                $PriceSearch . " ORDER BY VehDateadded DESC" ; "))
                                        {
                                                if ($result->num_rows != 0)
                                                {
                                                        $total_results = $result->num_rows;
                                                        // ceil() returns the next highest integer value by rounding up value
 if necessary
                                                        $total_pages = ceil($total_results / $per_page);

                                                        // check if the 'page' variable is set in the URL (ex: view-paginated
.php?page=1)
                                                        if (isset($_GET['page']) && is_numeric($_GET['page']))
                                                        {
                                                                $show_page = $_GET['page'];

                                                                // make sure the $show_page value is valid
                                                                if ($show_page > 0 && $show_page <= $total_pages)
                                                                {
                                                                        $start = ($show_page -1) * $per_page;
                                                                        $end = $start + $per_page;
                                                                }
                                                                else
                                                                {
                                                                        // error - show first set of results
                                                                        $start = 0;
                                                                        $end = $per_page;
                                                                }
                                                        }
                                                        else
                                                        {
                                                                // if page isn't set, show first set of results
                                                                $start = 0;
                                                                $end = $per_page;
                                                        }

                                                        // display pagination
                                                        echo "<p><a href='view.php'>View All</a> | <b>View Page:</b> ";
                                                        for ($i = 1; $i <= $total_pages; $i++)
                                                        {
                                                                if (isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] == $i)
                                                                {
                                                                        echo $i . " ";
                                                                }
                                                                else
                                                                {
                                                                        echo "<a href='view-paginated.php?page=$i'>$i</a> ";
                                                                }
                                                        }
                                                        echo "</p>";


                                                        <your code to display data>
```

Comment: I have tried to use your code, am getting the following error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in display.php on line 118

line 118 is: if ($result = $mysqli->query(""SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM vehicledetails WHERE VehName LIKE '" . $VehName .

I noticed there are two closing brackets } missing from your code - have added those, but the error is still there

Any suggestion how to resolve that error?